# Adding Extension to PHP.ini?

Tags: printing, xampp, php

I'm using Xampp, and added php_printer.dll inside ext folder and opened the php.ini to write down the following :
**`extension=php_printer.dll`** without `;`

I've created a print.php page for testing

```
<?php
$handle =printer_open("Xerox Phaser 6120 PS");
$handle = printer_open();
?>
```

And an error showed up :
**Fatal error: Call to undefined function printer_open() in C:\xampp\htdocs\frame\print.php on line 2**

Whats wrong with that ?

Comment: Are you sure you have .dll in the extension folder? Does apache report some errors in logs? Where did you find this dll?

Comment: @glavic I've download the .dll file from this site http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ ..Scroll down to find 2010 file.

Answer (score 0):

php_printer.dll is an old extension, not sure if it still works with recent php without compiling

But there is a known workaround, you can convert the output to pdf then using command line with adobe reader pdf executable like the following

```
//with print dialog
$print = `<PATH to acrobat reader>AcroRd32.exe /P PdfFile`

//silent print
$print = `<PATH to acrobat reader>AcroRd32.exe /N /T PdfFile PrinterName`
```